# npm install is not working npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! syscall mkdir npm ERR! path C:\Users\avtar~saini npm ERR! errno -4048

Tags: npm, npm-install

```
G:\angularProject\battingApp-update>npm i
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\avtar~saini
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\avtar~saini'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\avtar~saini'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\avtar~saini'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\avtar~saini'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\\Users\\avtar~saini'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\avtar~saini'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some permission issues.

First thing which you can do is run this command with administrative permissions.

If that doesn't work then You can try this with administrative permissions:

```sh
npm i --unsafe-perms
```

I think these should solve your problem